# how to avoid tomcat restart if we update xls file in classpath for spring Boot drools

Tags: spring-boot, drools

Below is the config class for loading xls rules file

```
@Configuration
public class DroolsConfiguration {
private final KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
@Bean
public KieContainer getKieContainer() {
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/FDInterestRate.xls"));
    KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kb.buildAll();
    KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
    return kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
}}
```

and below is the controller class

```
    @RestController
        public class FixedDepositRateController {
        private final KieContainer kieContainer;
        public FixedDepositRateController(KieContainer kieContainer) {
        this.kieContainer = kieContainer;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getFDInterestRate", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public FDRequest getQuestions(@RequestParam(required = true) String bank, @RequestParam(required = true) Integer durationInYear) {
        KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
        FDRequest fdRequest = new FDRequest(bank,durationInYear);
        kieSession.insert(fdRequest);
        kieSession.fireAllRules();
        kieSession.dispose();
        return fdRequest;
    }
}
```

So overall one config class(DroolsConfiguration) , one rest controller (FixedDepositRateController) and other class is FDRequest.java on which rules are applied. So pls suggest without restart of tomcat how can we reflect changes of xls file.

Comment: Much thanks for your time. Is it feasible if we create API for rewriting file after any update in rule file ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to store a reference to `KieFileSystem` and write the file again to kie file system after update?

```
kieFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules/FDInterestRate.xls"));
```

Comment: Much thanks for your time. Is it feasible if we create API for rewriting file after any update in rule file ?